# Azure Table Storage Bad Request - Error in query syntax

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

The following used to work.

```
      public void CreateTableIfMissing()
    {
        var info = new StorageInfo(); // initialized with tablename and connectionstring
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(info.ConnectionString);
        var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(info.TableName);
        try
        {
            table.CreateIfNotExists();
            var batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
            var s = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            var entry = new TableEntity("partkey"+s,"rowkey"+s);
            batchOperation.Insert(entry);
            table.ExecuteBatch(batchOperation);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Error information is

```
{Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: 
ErrorCode "InvalidInput"
Element 0 in the batch returned an unexpected response code.
StatusMessage:0:Bad Request - Error in query syntax
```

The table is in use for error logging via Serilog with an Azure sync.
I can see that it is still getting log records if I connect with Azure Storage Explorer.

I have not changed connection strings

[Update]

I am trying a single operation but having trouble

```
'TableOperation' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments
Cannot access internal constructor 'TableOperation' here
```

[image: single op]

[image: more info]

[Update]

If I follow Ivan's advice but omit the ToString("o") parameter the error is

```
ErrorMessage:The 'PartitionKey' parameter of value 'partkey3/7/2019 8:33:25 PM' is out of range.
```

This makes sense.

I wonder why it ever worked!

Comment: Why do you need a batch when there is only one entity operation inside? If you execute the Insert operation without a batch, you'll be able to see the detailed error information in StorageException which is easier for troubleshooting..

Comment: @KirstenGreed, the error is caused by the invalid chars "/" in the rowkey and partkey. So please use DateTime.Now.ToString("o") or other datetime does not contains "/" instead of DateTime.Now.ToString().

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update:**

For the error message in your previous code(not the update one):

```
{Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: 
ErrorCode "InvalidInput"
Element 0 in the batch returned an unexpected response code.
StatusMessage:0:Bad Request - Error in query syntax
```

The reason is that the partkey and rowkey in table storage does not accept characters like "/". And when you use DateTime.Now.ToString(),which contains characters "/", as the suffix of partkey and rowkey, then will cause the error.
Please format the datetime and remove the "/", you can use `DateTime.Now.ToString("o")` in your code(or other correct format).

**For the updated code:**

The error is because `TableOperation class` does not has constructor(parameter or parameterless). You can nav to TableOperation class and take a look at its usage.

[image]

In you case, you should use it's static `Insert method` like `var op = TableOperation.Insert(entry)` instead of `var op = new TableOperation(entry,TableOperationType.Insert)`.

And also one thing you need to know, the partkey and rowkey in table storage does not accept characters like "/", so when you use `datetime.now` for a suffix of partkey and rowkey, you should use `var s = DateTime.Now.ToString("o")`. Or it will cause error.

The sample code works fine for me:

```
        public void CreateTableIfMissing()
        {
           var info = new StorageInfo(); // initialized with tablename and connectionstring
           var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(info.ConnectionString);
           var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
           var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(info.TableName);

            try
            {
                table.CreateIfNotExists();

                var s = DateTime.Now.ToString("o");
                var entry = new TableEntity("partkey" + s, "rowkey" + s);
                var op = TableOperation.Insert(entry);
                table.Execute(op);               

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

For more code samples about table storage, you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#create-a-table).

Comment: It's a great code example, but it doesn't fully answer the question. :) @kirsten-greed , please follow the code and see the error details in `StorageException.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation`.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft, I added the reason, this is due to DateTime.Now.ToString() which contains an invalid chars "/". We can format the datetime by using DateTime.Now.ToString("o") or some other correct format datetime.

Comment: It's a great finding! I'm just a bit curious that how come it **used to** work when `DateTime.Now.ToString()` contains invalid characters for Partition Key and Row Key. It's supposed to never work.